# How to modify the style of the pop-up page displayed when the tab in the tabpane exceeds its width

Tags: java, javafx

How to modify the style where I draw the red circle? The most I can do is change the style of that button.

```css
.tab-pane-ui .control-buttons-tab .tab-down-button .arrow{
}
.tab-pane-ui .control-buttons-tab .tab-down-button{
}
.tab-pane-ui .control-buttons-tab{
}
```

[image]

I looked at the javafx css documentation, but nothing came of it.

Comment: What classes are you using to create that popup menu?

Comment: @VGR I'm assuming the OP is just referring to the built-in popup in a `TabPane`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not documented, but the popup is a `ContextMenu` which is shown with an owning node with style class `tab-down-button`.

So you can access the context menu in CSS with

```
.tab-down-button .context-menu {

    /* ... */
}
```

and use any of the [context menu substructure](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#contextmenu) from there.

For example:

style.css

```
.tab-down-button .context-menu .label {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Here is a test application with the above `style.css` file:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.tabstyle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20; i++) {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("Tab "+i));
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much